# Calling non-abstract method from a list of abstract objects

Tags: java

I have 5 classes. I have the domain class which constructs my objects.
I have an abstract class called "Component", which has some abstract method, some not abstract.
I have 3 classes "ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC" that implement Component.

Example code

```java
public abstract class Component {
    protected string name;

    public abstract double getVolume();
//Getter and setter for name
}

public class ItemA extends Component {
    private double radius;
    private double height;

    public double getVolume() {
        return pi * radius * radius * height;
    }

    public void setRadius(int p_radius) {
        this.radius = p_radius;
    }
}

public class domain {
    ArrayList<Component> componentList = new ArrayList<Component>();

    public void domain() {
        componentList.add(new ItemA(25, 10));
        componentList.setRadius(50); <<<<Says it doesn 't know what to do that.
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with abstract-ness. (`setRadius` isn't even an abstract method).

`componentList` is an ArrayList, **not** a `ItemA` instance with a `setRadius` method.

Did you want to `((ItemA) componentList.get(0)).setRadius(50)`?

Or cleaner...

```
ItemA a = new ItemA(25, 10);
a.setRadius(50);
componentList.add(a);
```

Comment: Right, but I was trying to avoid doing that otherwise in domain, whenever I want to make a method like "findLargestVolume()", I would have to go through all ItemA, ItemB, ItemC, instead of having a nice arraylist to just cycle through. Yeah I do admit that I made this example a bit quickly.

((ItemA) componentList.get(0)).setRadius(50) I did not try casting it actually, I did something like Item a = componentList.get(0) and it gave me an error. I will try to do as you said.

Comment: You can find the largest volume like `componentList.stream().mapToDouble(Component::getVolume).max()`... Why did you think you needed to use each item type?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. If you want to use abstract class for that. You should define that on Component class.

```
public abstract void setRadius(double radius);
```

Then override it on ItemA class like that;

```
public void setRadius(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
```

Then apply that;

```
componentList.get(0).setRadius(50);
```

Comment: This is making assumptions about the object model, though. Not all volumetric bodies have a radius